# Why do I get the JSP error "attribute for " is not properly terminated" when escaping quote in JSTL el expression?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat8, jsp-tags

I have been developing on Mac for over 8 years and I wanted to give Windows 10 another chance.  So I checked in all my projects into GitHub on the Mac and then synchronised the projects on my Windows 10 machine.

Once I ran the project in NetBeans and navigated to certain JSP pages, I received the following error...

> 18-May-2018 09:46:24.335 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-27]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Project] threw exception
>   [/WEB-INF/tags/config.tag (line: 46, column: 34) attribute for " is
>   not properly terminated] with root cause 
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/tags/config.tag (line: 46,
>   column: 34) attribute for " is not properly terminated

On the line specified I have the following...

```
<c:when test="${storageType == \"boolean\"}">
```

And whilst I could change it to the following...

```
<c:when test="${storageType == 'boolean'}">
```

I have many places in my tags and JSP where I've escaped the quotation ("), I don't see why I have to change this.  My project is working in production as-is, so I don't want to unnecessarily touch JSP / tag files.

On my Mac, which is using JDK 1.8.0_102 it works fine

On my Windows 10, which is using JDK 1.8.0_172 it is not working

I'm using NetBeans, with the forementioned JDKs.

Tomcat on Windows = 8.0.27.0

Tomcat on Mac = 8.0.23.0

**UPDATE**

This works..

```
<c:if test="${key == 'testing'}">
    <div>TESTING-A</div>
</c:if>
```

This does NOT work...

```
<c:if test="${key == \"testing\"}">
    <div>TESTING-A</div>
</c:if>
```

The latter causes the error at **runtime**

[/WEB-INF/tags/config.tag (line: 27, column: 12) attribute for " is not properly terminated] with root cause org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/tags/config.tag (line: 27, column: 12) attribute for " is not properly terminated.

I note column 12 is the first quotation …

To be clear, escaping in  the JSTL expression seems to be the root cause - but why is it not working on a newer Tomcat?

Comment: The expression is valid and works on the Mac, storageType is one of many types, e.g string | int | boolean | info, etc. So I'm comparing the storageType to see whether it equals boolean, which means it must be inside the ${…} evaluation - otherwise what's going to evaluate it?

Comment: yup, it needs to be inside the EL expression, EJP.

Answer (score 0):

If your `storageType` variable really is a boolean, you can check it like so:

```
<c:if test="${storageType eq false}">
```

If however it's just a string with value 'false' you should do a string comparison:

```
<c:if test="${storageType eq 'false'}">
```

Considering your particular example, you could do something like this:

```
<c:when test="${storageType eq true || storageType eq false}">
```

or for string comparrison

```
<c:when test="${storageType eq 'true' || storageType eq 'false'}">
```

But you really should first perform the first checks to see if your variable really is a boolean type and not just a string.

Comment: Thanks - storageType is a String, so I'm happy to change == to eq, but I'm unclear why it is working as-is on a different machine.

Comment: well your error is saying that your <c:when statement isn't being closed properly? Could you post the whole code snippet? I'm guessing it worked differently on your mac because maybe you didn't copy over all the libraries or something.

Comment: perhaps the settings in your IDE on your Mac has certain error checking disabled?

Comment: This works...
<c:if test="${key == 'testing'}">
    <div>TESTING-A</div>
</c:if>

This doesn't...
<c:if test="${key == \"testing\"}">
    <div>TESTING-A</div>
</c:if>

Comment: weird, seems like an edge case, both are using Netbeans yeah?

Comment: Indeed, both using NetBeans, but I suspect it's Tomcat or maybe the JRE/JDK that it's using at runtime.  Never experienced it before and as it's a runtime issue I could easily miss one edit - hence my desired to understand the root cause and fix it properly.

Comment: yeah that's very strange, curious to know what exactly is going on. Thought your question was about checking for boolean types, my bad.